# EV3 FLL Question " outside the box "

Tags: fll

I am joining our FLL team and I have a question can you please help me?

I'm working on the mission "outside the box" and my arm on the robot is not strong enough to lift the box in the air, so that the block in the box will fall out.

How can I make my robot arm stronger so that I can lift the box in the air?

Can it be that we have to place the with the gear on another place? for example: the big gear on the right side and the small gear on the left side or the other way around?

Comment: You'll need to clarify some things.  First, how are you powering your robot arm?  What gears are you using?  Have you tried other gear ratios to increase torque?

Comment: Similar to: [How can a lego-mindstorm robot lift something very heavy](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/5947/56)

Comment: Are you able to provide some pictures of what you've tried so far?